# REST payload/response data structure vs app data structure

Tags: python, rest, data-structures, hashmap, swagger

I have a Python app that consists of an API allowing users to pull some data and do some stuff (generate insights, etc. -- not really important I think). Each of the API endpoints require a user name as an input, e.g. `POST /insights?username=jimbo`. Each user has their own saved preferences (parameters), and based on these the API will behave slightly differently. While handling a single request the app may need to use several parameters, so I want to be able to access them quickly. I don't expect the parameters to be updated very often (and when they are, it's not time sensitive). Since I particularly want quick reads of a specific parameter, I figure a hash map (`dict`) makes the most sense to store this information.

So something like the following (I also need to track when the parameter was added for a different reason):

```
PREFERENCES_DICT = {
  username: {
    parameter: {
      "value": param_value,
      "date_added": param_date_added
    }
  }
}
```

An example of this (`username = "jimbo"` and `parameter = "max_entries"`):

```
PREFERENCES_DICT = {
  "jimbo": {
    "max_entries": {
      "value": 10,
      "date_added": "2022-12-15"
    }
  }
}
```

This means I can quickly access this `max_entries` parameter for user `jimbo` with:

```
PREFERENCES_DICT["jimbo"]["max_entries"]["value"]
```

I also have endpoints for getting/setting/etc. these preferences. The problem is that I feel like the data structure above doesn't really suit as a request payload or response (within e.g. `POST /preferences/users`). Because the keys are changing, I won't be able to define a Swagger model and therefore marshal (since the key names are different each time). I also think that without knowing the above data structure, it will be harder for users to understand what each node represents.

If we were to add a new user something like the following seems like it would make more sense:

```
payload = {
  "username": "jimbo",
  "parameters": [
    {
      "parameter_name": 'max_entries',
      "parameter_value": 10,
      # "parameter_date_added": "2022-12-15"  # auto-populated
    }
  ]
}
```

However, if I use this I'll need to convert between data structures. This isn't difficult to do but it will mean for each update I'll have to convert from the list data structure to the dict one, try to add it to the preferences `dict`, then convert back for the response. It also just feels kind of wrong having a data structure that is purely used as an input output but is immediately converted into something else.

Maybe I'm thinking about this all wrong...

**EDIT**
Stating my questions more explicitly: Is there a best practise solution here? Does it make sense to use one data structure for the request and convert to a different one for use within the app (and back again for the response)? If not, then what would be the best practise?

Comment: Is there a question here? That design seems fine, and it's good practice to separate the exposed request/response data structure from the internal app data structure.

Comment: Thanks @aaron. I've added an edit stating my question more explicitly. It seems like you've pretty much answered it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short:

The payload itself is fine if you consider the username as possibly if not likely the `key` for his/her preferences in your particular case. You can dump into both a RDBMS or NoSQL DB easily enough.

Long:

However, the second paylod is superior for other reasons. The username should not be the key or id for the data. The key should really be an id in `UUID` format. For example is `jimbo` your id for other collections?

Also keep in mind the following:

`POST` is not a query and thus should not have any query string. The endpoint `POST /insights` is for the creation of data on the `insights` collection.

Its valid and fine to issue a `PUT /insights/jimbo` and consider it an UPSERT -- update if the id exists; insert otherwise -- of data on the insights collection with `jimbo` as the id in that collection.

But as stated it should be `PUT /insights/975037c8-1f29-481b-8135-f2b1c2c216f4`.

Of course, `GET /insights?username=jimbo` make sense as it is a query on the `insights` collection where username (not id) is "jimbo"

Ill send you here for some easy [reading on endpoints and the such](https://jsonapi.org/format/#crud-creating)

Comment: and, I would go with your second json format for the reason that aaron mentioned that "it's good practice to separate the exposed request/response data structure from the internal app data structure"